# how to run chef-client remotely with dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to run chef-client remotely using knife run, however I would like to supply set of attributes at run time.

```
knife winrm -m 10.10.10.10 -x myuser -P mypassword chef-client
```

Ideal command:

```
knife winrm -m 10.10.10.10 -x myuser -P mypassword chef-client -j c:\.chef\dna.json
```

Comment: That's not how chef is written to work at first. It is a pull model. Hard to give any more advice without a clue of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Node attribute data lives on the Chef Server, so you set it there (`knife node edit`, etc) rather than when you run `chef-client`. In general you can't easily change per-node data after initial creation, at least not without a bunch of caveats.

Comment: so then command would be as follows:    knife cookbook upload myrecipe; knife winrm -m 10.10 .10.10 -x username -P mypasss chef-client

Comment: Uploading a cookbook isn't related just to attributes, but sure that's a pretty common thing to do for very simple Chef workflows.